# Sort of SyncLock

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I'm checking out this code, and it's **doing something similar to a SyncLock** but instead of the other threads waiting, they skip over the code.

The code is doing it with variables; I'm wondering if there’s a build-in .net function that does this?

```
Private _previousValueCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub F()
   If _previousValueCount = 0 Then
       _previousValueCount = 1
       ' ...
       _previousValueCount = 0
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: BTW, that code is **not** thread-safe; that is *basically* the same as the `Interlocked` version I posted, but with the distinction that `Interlocked` *is* thread-safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make use of **[Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270976.aspx)** class which tries to acquire a lock on **any kind of global object**. If you do not get a *lock within* a certain *timespan/milliseconds*, you can act as you want.

```
bool acquiredLock = false;
try
{
  Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, 1000, ref acquiredLock);
  if (acquiredLock)
  {
    // got lock, do something
  }
  else
  {
    // no lock - warning/error/...
  }
}
finally
{
  if (acquiredLock)
     Monitor.Exit(lockObject);  // release lock!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing it; one way is to do something like:

```
int lockTaken = 0;

...

bool haveLock = false;
try {
    haveLock = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lockTaken, 1, 0) == 0;
    if(haveLock) {
       // it was zero, it is now one; you won the lock: do something
    }
} finally {
    if(haveLock) Interlocked.Exchange(ref lockTaken, 0);
}
```

Another way is to use `Monitor.TryEnter` with a zero timeout:

```
readonly object syncLock = new object();
...
bool haveLock = false;
try {
    Monitor.TryEnter(syncLock, 0, ref haveLock);
    if(haveLock) {
      // you won it; do something
    }
} finally {
    if(haveLock) Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
}
```